# Fluctuating voltage coming out of arduino uno 3.3 output pin

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, voltage-level

Problem with my arduino is when I check voltage of 3.3 volt pin using multimeter , voltage varries a lot from 1.5v upto 5v. Due to which esp8266 wifi module connected to this 3.3v pin gets very hot.

Is the arduino is faulty or can me made to produce steady 3.3 v . Kindly suggest .

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your circuit.

Comment: The ESP8266's power consumption is higher than the power regulator on the Arduino UNO board can deliver. You have to find another power source!

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino cannot power an ESP8266 directly.

A genuine Arduino has the LP2985 which can provide up to 150mA (about a quarter of what you need for an ESP8266) and will go into "thermal shutdown" when it gets overloaded.

However, a Chinese (or other cheap) clone could use something even less powerful, with or without thermal protection.  In this case overloading the 3.3V pin could irreversibly damage the 3.3V regulator (which may be internal to the USB chip, killing the USB connection in the process) and thus render it unable to regulate the voltage down to 3.3V properly.

If the latter is the case then it is also possible that the higher voltage passed through by the failed regulator could have also killed the ESP8266 chip.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure the voltage is stable without load. Voltage fluctuations are sign of not enough current available.

If you look into the Uno specs, you will find out that the 3.3 V pin can supply max 50 mA.

If you look into esp8266 datasheet in power section you will find out that it needs far more current than 50 mA.

Power the esp8266 from 5V pin over a voltage converter.

Comment: Actually that limit of 50mA is a lie. It *used* to be the case, when the 3.3V was taken from the internal regulator of the FT232 chip (that pin was actually intended to just have a capacitor on it, but Arduino decided to leach power from there too), and that was limited to 50mA. But the LP2985 3.3V regulator used on modern Uno boards can actually provide up to 150mA. Still, that's way below what the ESP8266 needs, so your answer is still correct :)

Comment: I have only Uno WiFi and it can 1A from 3.3V pin :).

Comment: Is that all? I have the chipKIT Pro MZ (one of only 10 in existence) and it can provide 3A from the 3.3V pin :P  Thanks to the TPS82130SILT (sexxxxiest regulator module ever created...!)